# Implementing an image into a GUI

Tags: image, matlab, matlab-guide

I am making a GUI in MATLAB and I also want to implement the picture with  the logo in it. How can I implement it permanently, so after compiling it to an app the logo won't have to be stored on a computer?

Thank you in advance!

I have tried this:

```
 axes(hObject)
 imshow('logo.png')
```

Comment: Obviously the image must be stored somewhere on the computer for you to see it. Can you be more specific about your requirements? GUIDE already gives you two files that have to be in the same place (the .fig file and the .m file) so is there really a problem with having three?

Comment: When I compile the app, I want be able to see the logo in it without storing the logo on a computer.
The code provided above is implemented in .m file.

Comment: The fact that you're compiling the app is exactly the kind of detail you need to include in the question! The Application Compiler allows you to manually add files required for your app to run, and these are embedded into the compiled executable. I'm moderately surprised that the above code in your M-file isn't enough to get the image automatically added to the list though.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: If that's the problem you're actually trying to solve please edit your question and then when you get an answer other users with the same question will be able to find it.

Comment: The question has been edited.